# Junit categories - which category I am in?

Tags: java, junit, automation, categories

I am using JUNIT's @categories and want to check in a method which category I am in.

for example
if (category.name == "sanity")
//do something

Is there any way to do that?
**I want to avoid having to pass a parameter to this method because I have over 800 calls to it in the project**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do that the same way that can be used to determine if any other class has specific annotation and its values - use Java reflection mechanism.

As a quick example for your specific case you can make it like this:

```java
@Category(Sanity.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testWhatever() {
        if (isOfCategory(Sanity.class)) {
            // specific actions needed for any tests that falls into Sanity category:
            System.out.println("Running Sanity Test");
        }
        // test whatever you need...
    }

    private boolean isOfCategory(Class<?> categoryClass) {
        Class<? extends MyTest> thisClass = getClass();
        if (thisClass.isAnnotationPresent(Category.class)) {
            Category category = thisClass.getAnnotation(Category.class);
            List<Class<?>> values = Arrays.asList(category.value());
            return values.contains(categoryClass);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```